# Connecting oracle 12c with php 7.1.7

Tags: php, oracle12c

I have oracle 12c R2 installed and xampp with php 7.1.7. Oracle 12c is 64 bit on my 64 bit windows 10 machine. But xampp is 32 bit.

How do I connect my oracle 12c with php?

Do I need to download oracle 12c 32 bit client and then use oci8?

Answer (score 1):

If XAMPP is 32-bit, then you need 32-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH since the PHP executable & OCI8 extension will be running as 32-bit.

If you also have a database on the same machine, make sure not to stuff up anything if you change PATH globally.  You might need to change PATH just for XAMPP.

The Oracle Net layer between PHP OCI8 and the database will handle any 32-bit to 64-bit data conversions.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to put the same version client in your computer. This will automatically get the environment variable and everything right.